# neko vm ? need to download like jvm?

Tags: java, neko

i new to neko vm. may i know in order to use it, i need to download the vm and install on client's browser? it is the same like java vm right? what is the different from java applet using jvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/) home page, it doesn't appear to be something that is a browser plugin. It appears to be more designed for embedding into a C/C++ application, sort of like [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

I'm sure the NekoVM web site does a better job explaining its use than I could.

Answer (score 1):

From a [Neko Mailing List Post](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.neko.general/2007-06/msg00004.html):

> Neko is not intended to be available
>   as a web browser plugin, so we don't
>   really care about VM availability on
>   the target user computer. Neko is very
>   lightweight so it can be included
>   directly in all applications using it.